# wx.Panel in a wx.Panel

Tags: python, wxpython, panel, wxwidgets

When I embed a `wx.Panel` in another `wx.Panel` (here `ChildPanel` is embedded in `MyPanel`), by default this ChildPanel doesn't use the *full* size of the parent. Why?

**Is there a trick for saying that `ChildPanel` should use full space of `MyPanel` ?
Is it possible without a `BoxSizer` ?**

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#00f8f8')

        # ChildPanel
        self.ChildPanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.ChildPanel.SetBackgroundColour('#000000')

class DrawFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()        

app = wx.App(False)
F = DrawFrame(None, title="Test", size=(500,500))
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: you would need to put it in a sizer with wx.GROW or wx.EXPAND as one of its flags ...  Or manually set the size from the kwargs if its not resizable..mypanel is likely not filling the frame either since it is not added to a sizer and you are not passing a size argument to the constructor... this question really confuses me.. why would you expect the panel to fill the frame or the current panel if you dont set a size or sizer?

Comment: Isn't it possible without a `sizer` ?
I thought the childpanel could fill the frame or panel *by default*, without using a size.

Comment: For example : by default, a `wx.Panel` fill the parent `wx.Frame` without using a sizer.

Comment: no it doesnt ... not typically ... they may both have the same default size(so if you pass no size arguments, they would be the same size) or if you bubble the size argument to the panel... why dont you just use a sizer or manually set the size?

Comment: it does: try the code here, there is no `size` argument when creating `MyPanel`. However `MyPanel` fills 100% of the parent `DrawFrame`, even with no sizer, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wxFrame` is a special case and is the only window which resizes its *only* child to entirely fill up its client area. Other windows, including `wxPanel`, don't do this, so you do need to use a sizer -- or position the child panel manually in `wxEVT_SIZE` handler.

Of course, if you think about it, it makes sense: while it's pretty common to have a `wxPanel` entirely covering up the `wxFrame`, it's very rare to have a `wxPanel` or `wxWindow` as the only child of another `wxPanel` because it simply doesn't make any sense to do it, you're just wasting a window for nothing (and windows are a relatively heavy resource, so you shouldn't do this).